# Perl Inheritance - Who's the caller of the Parent Class

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have a situation where I need to find the caller of a package and my code looks something like:

Inherited.pm:

```
package Inherited;
our @ISA = qw(BaseClass);
sub new {
   SUPER::new();
}
```

BaseClass.pm

```
package BaseClass;
sub new {
  $a = caller(0);
  print $a
}
```

Now I have another class (MyClass.pm) which does:
MyClass.pm:

```
$obj = Inherited->new();
```

This prints Inherited. But I need **MyClass** to be the printed statement.

Could someone please help me out on how to solve this ??

Comment: I don't understand why you would expect this. `Inherited` is the caller.  You could check in the `new()` of `Inherited` and then pass that information on.

Comment: @Cfreak: thanks for the response. Ya i accept that passing via argument is a solution, but is there any other way to find the caller of the parent class. In my actual scenario i need this kind of a functionality without passing arguments.

Comment: You might be able to use `Carp`'s stack-trace ability to search the whole list of callers (`Carp::longmess()`) but it's not a great solution. Take a peek at the `Class::*` modules on CPAN. There might be a more elegant solution there.

Comment: Just to add. Another solution might be to make `MyClass` inherit from `Inherited` instead of calling it. You could then use `isa()` in the base class to check for `MyClass` (you still have to check explicitly though)

Comment: What?! Your not using [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0403/lib/Moose.pm)?

Comment: @Cfreak: Yes I'm using ISA to inherit Inherited Class from Base Class. I forgot to add that line. I'll edit the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you give [caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) an argument, you tell it how many levels to go back. You've given it the argument `0`, which is the current level. If you want one level up, add `1`:

```
use v5.12;

package Inherited {
    our @ISA = qw(BaseClass);
    sub new {
       $_[0]->SUPER::new();
    }
}

package BaseClass {
    sub new {
      say "0: ", scalar caller(0);
      say "1: ", scalar caller(1);
    }
}

package MyClass {
    my $obj = Inherited->new;
    }
```

Now the result is:

```
0: Inherited
1: MyClass
```

Remember to always include complete example programs in your questions. The Perl code you posted was broken for various other reasons unrelated to [caller](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html).

Comment: I think the Carp module does something like this: if the caller is "related" to the croaker, it skips to the next caller instead.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your post correctly, you need to find the last frame in the call stack that is calling a constructor.

```
package BaseClass;
sub new {
    my $a = caller(0);
    for (my $n=0; my @c=caller($n); $n++) {
        last if $c[4] !~ /::new$/;
        $a = $c[0];
    }
    print $a;
}
```

or

```
package BaseClass;
sub new {
    my @a;
    unshift @a, [ caller(@a) ] while caller(@a);
    my ($a) = grep { $_->[4] =~ /::new$/ } @a;
    print $a // caller(0);
}
```

The second code snippet will handle the case when there are intermediate function calls that are not constructors, e.g., if the call stack looks like

```
 GrandChild::new
 GrandChild::init
 Inherited::new
 BaseClass::new
```

the first snippet would return the caller for `Inherited::new` (which presumably would be `GrandChild`, and the second one would return the caller of `GrandChild::new`.

Comment: thanks for the response. Your solution is also working for me but sadly i cannot accept more than one answer here.